# RegEx: match digits from a comma-seperated number

Tags: regex, openoffice-writer

I want to only match the digits from a comma seperated number. Example:

```
123,456 should match 123 and 456
75,432,444 should match 75 and 432 and 444
```

My expression currently looks like this `\b[0-9]+(!\,)?+\b`. It matches numbers that are NOT seperated with a comma, but it doesn't select numbers that are seperacted with a coma. If I seperate numbers with a | character or a space the numbers are selected.

Splitting the string is not an option.
I'm trying to learn RegEx, but I'm now stumbled at this.

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: Don't try to match the whole string, just split it by `,` and store the resulting array.

Comment: How does it not work?  What do you get?  what are you looking to get?  Why isn't `\d+` sufficient?

Comment: Rather than using language like "doesn't work the way I want it", please include what the result is and what you expect the result to be.

Comment: You also may consider \b[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*\b Which means 'at least one sequence of digits, and any number (including zero) comma followed by some digits' repeated. But as other commenters have mentioned, scope and language are important here.

Comment: If you're trying to match comma, why do you have `!` in your regular expression?

Comment: It's not a programming language, I'm trying to match it in OpenOffice Writer.

@Barmar, because I'm not trying to match comma.

Comment: '!' is not "not" in regex usually, typically it's [^!] meaning 'a character not in the set "!"'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
\b(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)\b
```

It matches numbers that are separated by commas in group of three. Once you have the number in the capturing parentheses you can split on comma if you want to have its parts separated.